# How do you add images in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

So I'm trying to add an image of my logo into an Angular5/ Ionic project.

I'm using an HTML file as a template then I call it in all the files where it needs to be used.

Unfortunately, if I try to add the image in the HTML template file, I get an error in the browser console stating the following:

http://localhost:4200/src/assets/images/Pair_and_Share_Business_Card_Front_Final_Edit_v2-1.png 404 (Not Found)

I have tried calling the picture from component.ts file with no success
I have tried creating new folders inside the assets
I have tried renaming the logo file

```
<main>
<section>
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="signUp()">
<h3>Welcome to Pair Share</h3>
<body>
<img 
src="/src/assets/images/Pair_and_Share_Business_Card_Front_Final_Edit_v2- 
1.png">
</body>
<p>Lets get started</p>

<mat-form-field [formGroup]="signUpForm">
<input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" [formControl]="email" 
required>
<mat-error *ngIf="email.valid">Not a valid email</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field [formGroup]="signUpForm">
<input matInput placeholder="Enter your password" [type]="hide ? 
'password' : 'text'" [formControl]="password" required>
<mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 
'visibility_off' }}</mat-icon>
<mat-error *ngIf="password.valid">Not a valid password</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="accent">Sign up</button>


</form>
</section>
</main>
```

The id is expecting that since this the template file that I'm currently using for a signup page, that after adding an image like in a normal HTML file, it would get the image from its given folder and it would show up the on sign up page.

My signup.component.ts file has a @Component that is importing a template URL from this signup.component.html and this is the following code that I have.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css', '../auth.style.css']
})
```

So how come my logo is not showing up on the app?

Could anyone please help me out.

PS: Bear with me, I'm new to all of this stuff, and I might have beginner questions.

Comment: Is "src" the correct folder? Normally you copy assets to your dist folder and reference them using just /assets/. If you open your angular.json file you can see where this happens, i.e. why the files from the assets folder is copied.

Comment: Yes thats the correct folder there. I am using VS code and its automatically showing me the given paths, therefore i know the path shouldnt be a problem.

I have just tried going into teh angular.json file, and i added a new path under the assets "src/assets/images" sine thats the folder containing the logo and nothing has changed it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Ok, it's just that personal experience and [tutorials online](https://scotch.io/courses/build-your-first-angular-website/adding-an-imagelogo-in-angular) say otherwise, but if you say it's correct then my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the app, all files will be read from some sort of build folder. In Angular apps this would be `dist` and in Ionic (Cordova) it is `www`. You should never have `src` in the image path as this directory won't exist when your app is compiled. If you remove the `/src/` from your image reference (i.e. use `<img src="assets/images/Pair_and_Share_Business_Card_Front_Final_Edit_v2-1.png">`), it should work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the folder structure and image call is as follows

component: `[my-app]/src/app/components/[my-component]`
Image : `[my-app]/src/assets/images/[my-image]`

In order to access an image located in the images folder from a component, you should use the following structure

```
<img src="/assets/images/[your-image.png]>
```

notice the trailing slash before assets.

Answer (score 0):

On ionic5 with angular, all of the following paths works fine in my tests under ionic serve. I have not tested this on the actual device.

`<img src="assets/imgs/facebook.png">`
`<img src="/assets/imgs/facebook.png">`
`<img src="../assets/imgs/facebook.png">`
`<img src="/../assets/imgs/facebook.png">`
`<img src="../../assets/imgs/facebook.png">`

What does not work is when the case (png/PNG) does not match with filename in the folder. This is in Ubuntu environment.

On Ionic3 in Windows, mismatch case on filename extension is ok.